# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unittest (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for unittest

Tags: pip, python-unittest

*Recently I have been installed Python 3.8.2 ( Feb 24, 2020) (64bit, Windows). Afterward, I've been updated Pip 20.0.2. And then trying to install Unittest" pip install unittest" but unfortunately it's appearing this message. 
Does anyone has been faced this same problem?*

C:\Users\BiploB>pip install unittest --user
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unittest (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for unittest

[enter link description here](https://scontent.fdac16-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s960x960/91677108_10222510790940625_319629271440031744_o.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=ca434c&_nc_ohc=B1dExD-YVgMAX9KUkEX&_nc_ht=scontent.fdac16-1.fna&_nc_tp=7&oh=c4ecd9d4edc8c4b73536d12a0c73cb20&oe=5EADF7C4)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear what you are asking. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I know unittest is inbuilt with python. It's not only in unittest . It's also happed, when I even write pip list.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) is part of *Python*'s standard library. Meaning, it's available per default, meaning there is no need (and also no way) to install separately.